# Is there a way to fix or bypass weird time formats in a specific column in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, datetime, slurm, timedelta

I am working with a SLURM dataset in Pandas that has time formats like so in the 'Elapsed' column:

```
00:00:00
00:26:51
```

However, sometimes there are sections that are greater than 24 hours, and it displays it like so:

```
1-00:02:00
3-01:25:02
```

I want to find the mean of the entire column but it mishandles the to_timedelta conversion on the entries with entries above 24 hours like shown above. One example is this:

```
Before to_timedelta: 3-01:25:02
after to_timedelta: -13 days +10:34:58
```

I cannot simply convert the column into a new format because when entry is not greater than 24 hours, preceding zeros do not exist, ex: `0-20:00:00`
This method would be easiest I believe if there is a way however.

Is there a way to fix this conversion or any other ideas on approaching this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go around is replacing `-` with `days`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].str.replace('-','days'))
```

Output (for 4 lines above):

```
0   0 days 00:00:00
1   0 days 00:26:51
2   1 days 00:02:00
3   3 days 01:25:02
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: wow, did not even realize how easy it was! I had tried `str.split` at first to try and break it down but it just made a huge mess. Thank you, stay safe!